# Get href value from Category Selection

Tags: php

I want to get values of clicked links in the final page.

```
e.g. Computer & Network/Components and parts  -- New York /City
```

Example.

Page1

```
$Category = $_POST["cat"];
$Subcategory =$_POST["Subcat"]
```

Page 2

```
$Province = $_POST["Province"];
$City =$_POST["City"]

{echo "You selected to post on"$Category . "Subcategory" In $Province . $City}
```

I want to use links not submit button to display selected links

Comment: Its `<a href="something"` not `ref` as in your title. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use COOKIES.
But I recommend using the get method to pass them via url, and that is described in the other answers here.

Example

Page1

```
$Category = $_POST["cat"];
$Subcategory =$_POST["Subcat"];
$_COOKIE["cat"] = $Category;
$_COOKIE["Subcat"] = $Subcategory;
```

Page 2

```
$Category = $_COOKIE["cat"];
$Subcategory =$_COOKIE["Subcat"];
$Province = $_POST["Province"];
$City =$_POST["City"];
echo "You selected to post on".$Category . "Subcategory In". $Province . $City;
```

Answer (score 2):

USE `$_GET`

**for example :**

```
<a href="page.php?cat=Category&subcat=Subcategory&province=Province&city=City">link</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo "You selected to post on" . $_GET["cat"] . "/" . $_GET["subcat"] . " - " . $_GET["province"] . "/" . $_GET["city"];
```

Comment: Thanks, i want it to display like this Computer & Network/ Computer Parts - United States / Newyork . 

Is that the code i should use? I want to display after user selected all categories. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this sort of thing is accomplished with $_GET variables, rather than $_POST variables. These go after the document name in the URL. Like so:

site.com/myPage.php?cat=Category&subcat=Subcategory

If you absolutely need POST (for reasons I'm not sure I'd understand) you may be able to use a Javascript framework like JQuery to make invisible forms that post when you click a link. Just realize this is going to make navigation hell...each time someone clicks 'Back', the browser will warn them they may be resubmitting information.

Comment: Yes i want to use Get, how many pages do i need? Im a noob here Thanks,

Comment: You should just need two pages. Each page can react somewhat dynamically based on what parameters are present. To clarify, from the above URL, there's no need to create a file named "myPage.php?cat=Category...". When given that full URL, the server will know to just look for "myPage.php", and give it those $_GET parameters.